# Time trial login that expires Django

Tags: django, authentication

So I have a Django app set up with auth and a few Groups and users.  What I'm trying to do now is have a timed trial so users could have a login that would expire after 7 days. I've researched this and haven't been able to find anything. Feel like I'm missing something obvious. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the session is in a cookie, I'm guessing `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can make a function in your view to handle it. Everytime a request is made, call this function to check if the expiry date has ended.